# Is there a way to update/modify multiple rows at a time in different ways in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have two tables in PostgreSQL and get incoming CSVs with new information daily. For reference this is a gym so everyone has IDs, addresses, when their membership terminates, etc.

So I have a table memberships that contains all this metadata. Each time a CSV comes in I want to add rows of new members and alter any changed metadata of existing members.

At the same time, I want to log all of these changes in a separate 'Actions' table.

So say that I have

```
John, 33, 1234 A St, Anchorage, AK, 555-555-5555
```

That goes in to my main 'memberships' table and also goes into the 'Actions' table as 'new'.

If the next day for some reason `John` sends in a change of address, the `memberships` table updates to

```
John, 33, 6789 B St, Anchorage, AK, 555-555-5555
```

No new row is created. In the actions table a new row is created, it has John's `member ID` (serial PK) and nulls except the address value, which now says `6789 B St` and the action `Updated`

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in batches if the information is all coming in simultaneously (say I have 10 members who all need updated metadata in different ways, one changed her phone number and another changed his address). I know that I can do all of this one by one, but that seems expensive and so I'm wondering if there's a way to do it in fewer queries

If I have 300 rows with modifications can I do all at once or must I do one row at a time?

Googling around it seems like there might be something with `WHILE` and `IF`, but I'm also just wanting to know if I'm on the right track here, as I can't find a solution for this specific answer googling around. It seems like it is possible to do batch insertions and deletions (if all of them are new, or all of them are being removed) but I don't know about with modifications that might not be the same (maybe some are new, some need to be modified, and some need to be deleted).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for an [audit trigger](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)

Comment: As for the "Update unless it's a new member, then insert" is called an `Upsert` operation. Postgres performs this using the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` You can read up on that on the [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) of their manual.

Comment: How do you know that this John is the same John that's already in your table?

Comment: Jeremy - in this example John is just random data I'm using to protect information I can't share. The project I'm trying to solve this for, John would be replaced by a unique index number, so I'm not worried about John being the same or a different John,

Answer (score 0):

In SQL if you want to multiple things at time the fastest way to do this is joins and selects NOT while.  Loops are bad in SQL.

Since you need to do joins in SQL you need to have the data you want to use in a table.  Typically this is done via "Staging Tables".   These are tables where the new data is placed and then can be joined against as it gets put into the system.

For example in your case the 300 staging members information would be placed in a stage_memeber table and then you can run an update to your main table by joining on this table.   This would be a single query and update statement.

You can then left join to find the items that don't exist and feed this to an instert statement -- again a single query.

At times you might want to then put the staging data into an archive to an audit table so you know what you have done in the past.  Or you could summarize and write data to your audit system based on what is in your staging table before you clear it out for the next load.

You should be able to find more information about leading practices in this area by searching on ETL (for extract transform load) or "Loading data from Staging Tables" on popular search websites.

Comment: Thanks so much! I''ll check this out.